# Cannot create a folder or access it at specific location on Mavericks

Tags: macos, terminal, ntfs

Cannot create a directory and can neither go into directory.

`$/Volumes/Iomega_HDD/Movies` is an Windows NTFS file system mounted on my OS X Mavericks

so in the Movies folder if I try to create folder named 1940 it gives Input/output error but if I create outside Movies folder it gets created without any error.

if I type `ls 194` and hit tab it gets autocompleted as if it is there, but if I then hit enter after autocompletion it again gives I/O error.

`$:/Volumes/Iomega_HDD/Movies$ ll 1940`
ls: 1940: Input/output error

```
$ ls -laO /Volumes/Iomega_HDD/
total 1120
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -       20480 Nov 22 15:30 .
drwxrwxrwx@ 4 root          admin  hidden    136 Nov 22 18:45 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -           0 Nov 22 15:23 .Trashes
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -           0 Aug 29 00:17 .fseventsd
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -        4096 Sep  3  2012 Apple Computer
-rwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -           0 Apr  6  2013 Capture.PNG
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -       57344 Apr 14  2013 Footages
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -       12288 Nov 22 13:12 Miscellaneous
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -        8192 Nov 27  2012 Motherboard
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -       32768 Nov 22 18:04 Movies
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -        4096 Dec 22  2012 Projects
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -        4096 Aug 29 00:33 Softwares
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -       40960 Jan 30  2013 Songs
drwxrwxrwx  1 Ciastopiekarz  staff  -        8192 Aug 29 00:41 Tutorials
```

any idea how can i fix this ?

Comment: Do you have NTFS write enabled? NTFS-3G or similar? Mac cannot write to NTFS natively. I'd also wonder about using `$` in a file name, but I can't find anything that says is specifically not allowed on Mac or Win - on the other hand it might confuse Terminal, I'm not sure, but I'd avoid it.

Comment: its copied from shell thats why `$` got copied along with but its not part of any name, just part of tty., in the same directory I can create a folder by other name but not a folder named  `1940`. it feels to me file system has got corrupt

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Is ".../Movies$ ll 1940" just a spelling error or what kind of command is `ll`? Please add the output of  `ls -laO /Volumes/Iomega_HDD`!

Comment: @klanomath I have updated it in the post

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Please add the output of the  **superior** folder: `ls -laO /Volumes/Iomega_HDD`! I still try to understand the meaning of `$:/Volumes/Iomega_HDD/Movies$ ll 1940`.

Comment: @klanomath done.